# pandas groupby - custom function

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe to which I use groupby and sum():

```
d = {'col1': ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C","C"], 'col2': [1,2,3,4,5,6, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.groupby("col1").sum()
```

This results in the following:

```
col1 col2   
A   6.0
B   15.0
C   0.0
```

I want C to show NaN instead of 0 since all of the values for C are NaN.  How can I accomplish this?  Apply() with a lambda function?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the logic `NaN` because *every* value is `NaN`? For a group with `1 2 NaN` should you return NaN or 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @piRSquared, @Alollz, and @anky_91:

You can use without setting index and reset index:

```
d = {'col1': ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C","C"], 'col2': [1,2,3,4,5,6, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.groupby("col1", as_index=False).sum(min_count=1)
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2
0    A   6.0
1    B  15.0
2    C   NaN
```

Comment: This works perfectly.  Very clever.  Wouldn't have thought to check the sum() arguments.  Thanks all again for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
df.groupby('col1').apply(pd.DataFrame.sum,skipna=False).reset_index(drop=True)
#Or --> df.groupby('col1',as_index=False).apply(pd.DataFrame.sum,skipna=False)
```

Without the `apply()` thanks to @piRSquared:

```
df.set_index('col1').sum(level=0, min_count=1).reset_index()
```

thanks @Alollz :
If you want to return sum of groups containing NaN and not just NaNs

```
df.set_index('col1').sum(level=0,min_count=1).reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
  col1  col2
0  AAA   6.0
1  BBB  15.0
2  CCC   NaN
```

Comment: without the `apply`... `df.set_index('col1').sum(level=0, skipna=False).reset_index()`

Comment: @piRSquared always a genius logic. :) if you want you can post an answer and thanks for the upvote. :)

Comment: Nah.  It's too similar to yours in spirit.  It belongs as a comment here or in your post.  Feel free to add it if you'd like.

Comment: @piRSquared thanks , learned this concept can be used for a lot of ops i use daily. Thanks for all your answers. :)

Comment: @piRSquared only problem here is when A and B contain NaN the result will be NaN

Comment: Yeah I think this might be `min_count=1`

Comment: @ALollz I think you're right. (-:  Well depending on if OP wants just one `nan` to blow up the whole group or only if all `nan`

Comment: @ALollz that makes more sense to me. feel free to post an answer. :)

Comment: @ALollz its no shame to say that i do not know to apply min count in the right way. :(

Comment: What I need is if all the group is NaN, then the "sum" should result in NaN.  Just FYI, the real life context here is reduction in patient payments due.  A numeric value indicates a patient payment has been reduced to that value  A zero indicates the patient payment has been reduced to zero.  An NaN indicates that there is no reduction and the full amount is due.

Comment: My same answer but with `min_count`  `df.set_index('col1').sum(level=0, min_count=1).reset_index()`

Comment: @piRSquared aha..! thanks. i was trying `df.set_index('col1').sum(level=0, skipna=False,min_count=1).reset_index()` :P

Comment: @ALollz thanks a lot. Updated your suggestion too..!!

Answer (score 1):

make the call to sum have the parameter skipna = False.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html

that link should provide the documentation you need and I expect that will fix your problem.